# Implementing sorting algoritms on a struct

Tags: c, bubble-sort, selection-sort

I am writing a program that calculates the winner of an election using the Tideman electorial system.

I have defined a struct called pair, in which two candidates are compared. The index of the candidate with the most votes is represented by `winner` and the candidate with the least votes by `loser`.

```
// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;
```

these pairs are stored in a `pairs array`

```
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];
```

I am trying to sort this pairs array in decreasing order of strength of victory (defined as vote count for `winner` minus vote count for `loser`).

candidates are indexed into `vote_count` via their candidate index and the elements return their vote count. MAX pertains to the maximum number of candidates.

```
int vote_count[MAX]; // where i is the index of the candidate and the return value is the number of votes.
```

Here is my implementation of a selection sort:

```
int max_idx;  // index of element with the highest strength of victory

// one by one move boundary of unsorterd subarray
for (int i = 0; i < array_size - 1; i++)
{
    max_idx = i;
    
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array_size; j++)
    {
        if (vote_count[pairs[j].winner] - vote_count[pairs[j].loser] > vote_count[pairs[i].winner] - vote_count[pairs[i].loser])
        {
            max_idx = j;
        }
    }

    if (max_idx != i)
    {
        // swap the element with the highest strength of victory with the first element
        swap(&pairs[max_idx], &pairs[i]);
    }
}
return;
```

And here is my implementation of bubble sort:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array_size-i-1; j++)
    {
        if (vote_count[pairs[j].winner] - vote_count[pairs[j].loser] > vote_count[pairs[j+1].winner] - vote_count[pairs[j+1].loser])
        {
            swap(&pairs[j], &pairs[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
return;
```

Each call the swap function:

```
void swap(pair *xp, pair *yp)
{
    pair temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
```

The `vote_count` array is filled during the call to another function, vote:

```
// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // iterate through candidates
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp (name, candidates[i]) == 0)          // if vote is for a valid candidate
        {
            // update rank array
            ranks[rank] = i;
            vote_count[i]++;
            return true;
        }

}
// if no candidate is found
return false;
```

}

Neither the selection sort or bubble sort is working for me, please let me know where i'm going wrong.

Comment: `&pairs[j]` is `pairs + j`. Also, what is `swap`? How do we know it's implemented correctly?

Comment: A debugging tool is useful for comfirming your expectations. What IDE are you using?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have now included the swap function, thank you

Comment: That sorting looks correct but all hinges on (a) whether `vote_count` is sufficient in size to be indexed by all of the lookups being done, and (b) whether `swap` works correctly. Alas, we have *neither* of those for validation, since no [mcve] was supplied.

Comment: Now you need to show sample input and output demonstrating that you actually have a problem...

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I am using the web-based CS50 IDE: ide.cs50.io

Comment: In C, `qsort()` is your friend. It will sort any array of anything with a highly-efficient and optimized sort algorithm. All you do is write the `compare` function to tell `qsort()` how to sort your array and you are done...

Comment: *"Neither the selection sort or bubble sort is working for me"* - you need to clarify what that *means*. If the input does not generate your expectations of output, *we need to know that*. We need to know the input (and its mechanics in code, don't just tell us about it; *show us* in your question), the expected output, the actual output, etc. Help us help you.

Comment: For reference, this question pertains to the [CS50 - Tideman](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/3/tideman/) problem. (which is actually one of the more interesting CS50 problems...)

Comment: Thank you @David I was struggling to comprehensively answer WhozCraig. The link should provide all the relevent background information.

Comment: I think one issue you are having is deciding what to sort on for the voter preferences. I wrote a Tideman implementation using `qsort()` some time ago which may help [CS50 Tideman Solution using qsort()](https://paste.opensuse.org/43281591). Link good for 30 days.

Answer (score 3):

This does not exactly answer your question as asked, but you could create a comparator function and use [`qsort`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html):

```
/* Vote count needs to be global or file static for this to work */
int vote_count[...];

...

int compare_pair(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    int d1 = vote_count[((const pair *)p1)->winner] - vote_count[((const pair *)p1)->loser];
    int d2 = vote_count[((const pair *)p2)->winner] - vote_count[((const pair *)p2)->loser];
    return d2 - d1;
}
```

You could write this as a one-liner if you wanted, but it would be harder to read.

The sort then becomes

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

qsort(pairs, MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2, sizeof(pair), compare_pair);
```

Comment: The `winner` and `loser` are (apparently) candidate identifiers, not win and loss counts. Their win counts are what is recorded in the mysterious `vote_count` array. This will still work with modification to the comparator, but all hinges on `vote_count` actually allowing indexing for all of the candidate ids in the domain, which I suspect is where the real problem lays.

Comment: @WhozCraig. Good catch. I hadn't noticed that originally. Fixed now

Comment: Yeah, and I suspect that indexing is where things are going off the rails. No way to know for sure without a proper mcve from the OP. The OPs selection sort looks correct, assuming `vote_count` is proper and all the winner and loser entries hold water.

Comment: @WhozCraig. My thought as well